# pyspark LDA get words in topics

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, lda, topic-modeling

I am trying to run LDA. I am not applying it to words and documents, but error messages and error-cause. each row is an error and each column is an error cause. A cell is 1 if error cause was active, and 0 if error cause was not active. 
Now I am trying to get for each created topic (here equivalent to a error pattern) the error-cause names (not just the index). The code I have until now and that seems to work is the following

```
# VectorAssembler combines all columns into one vector
assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=list(set(df.columns) - {'error_ID'}),
    outputCol="features")
lda_input = assembler.transform(df)

# Train LDA model
lda = LDA(k=5, maxIter=10, featuresCol= "features")
model = lda.fit(lda_input)

# A model with higher log-likelihood and lower perplexity is considered to be good.
ll = model.logLikelihood(lda_input)
lp = model.logPerplexity(lda_input)
print("The lower bound on the log likelihood of the entire corpus: " + str(ll))
print("The upper bound on perplexity: " + str(lp))

# Describe topics.
topics = model.describeTopics(7)
print("The topics described by their top-weighted terms:")
topics.show(truncate=False)

# Shows the result
transformed = model.transform(lda_input)
print(transformed.show(truncate=False))
```

My outputs are:

[image]
[image: for each row]
Based on https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda I added that part, which doesn't work:

```
 topics = model.topicsMatrix()
    for topic in range(10):
        print("Topic " + str(topic) + ":")
        for word in range(0, model.vocabSize()): 
            print(" " + str(topics[word][topic]))
```

How do I now get the top error-causes / find the columns corresponding to the term indices?

Answer (score -1):

In order to iterate over a DenseMatrix you need to convert it into an array.
This should not give error. However I am not sure about the printed result as it depends on your data.

```
topn_words = 10
num_topics = 10

topics = model.topicsMatrix().toArray()
for topic in range(num_topics):
    print("Topic " + str(topic) + ":")
    for word in range(0, topn_words): 
        print(" " + str(topics[word][topic]))
```

Comment: hi @Tolga, I tried this code but it still printed me some numbers instead of topic words. I am using spark 2.4.3 version

Comment: `Topic 0:
 30.17673729638776
 99.14231560215744
 6.66435717428376
 12.15504287041995
 18.982848683531195
 100.50830388771101
 -68.84233323370782
Topic 1:
 29.973596695840133
 98.1127093876147
 7.307128038415854
 12.078623258770016
 18.90257467334695
 96.68763877584024
 -67.47621948864617
Topic 2:
 29.40209579979105
 97.47622395948163
 5.6867501820791695
 12.088347117003329
 19.433579035205614
 97.89893275034943
 -67.58479307177592`